# Adding a table count to my listing of databases

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to list all my custom databases:

```
SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` AS 'Database',
       `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME` AS 'Character Set',
       `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` AS 'Collation'
  FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`
  WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME` NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
  ORDER BY `SCHEMA_NAME` ASC
```

But I want to include the number of tables in each database:

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, COUNT(*)
  FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
  GROUP BY `TABLE_SCHEMA`
```

...in a single table:

```
[
  0 => [ 'Database'=>'customDb1', ..., 'Table Count'=>3 ],
  1 => [ 'Database'=>'customDb2', ..., 'Table Count'=>8 ],
  2 => [ 'Database'=>'customDb3', ..., 'Table Count'=>0 ]
]
```

I know that running the first query, looping through each database in PHP, and running the second query is much less efficient than using something like a table `JOIN`, but I'm just not grasping the `JOIN` syntax. The [Lynda tutorial](https://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/MySQL-Essential-Training/139986-2.html) I'm taking just steams right through this rather (potentially) complex part of the language, and everything I try just throws errors or bad results.

I'm sure this is a common query for developers creating MySQL database interfaces. How do I add a table count to my listing of databases using *only* MySQL queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.`SCHEMA_NAME` AS 'Database',
       s.`DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME` AS 'Character Set',
       s.`DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` AS 'Collation',
       COALESCE(COUNT(t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`),0) as table_cnt
FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` s
LEFT JOIN `information_schema`.`TABLES` t
 ON(s.`SCHEMA_NAME` = t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`)
WHERE s.`SCHEMA_NAME` NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
GROUP BY s.`SCHEMA_NAME`
ORDER BY s.`SCHEMA_NAME` ASC
```

Comment: Yea I noticed that while you wrote that comment:) @colburton

Comment: Much appreciation. I guess I was using `JOIN`s when I needed `INNER JOIN`, which I still need to read up on the difference. This definitely speeds/cleans things up!

Comment: @philtune `INNER JOIN` is the same as `JOIN` , if you'd posted your attempt I would have told you what you did wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I had many bad attempts that were just guesses, I would be embarrassed to show them to anybody. :) Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Oh, I have one problem with this. It only shows databases that have tables defined. I still want to include empty databases in my list.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` - * wildcard mean ALL, so what it does is counting ALL records, each records equal to 1. After the join each record will be constructed from both `SCHEMATA` and `TABLES` , so it just count how many rows like this was fetched.

Comment: @philtune Then you need a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` . Updated. I suggest you try selecting * from this query, not specific fields and see what this query does.

Comment: Woah, never heard of COALESCE. Well, I got my empty databases back, but the empty ones show 1 tbl_count instead of 0.

Comment: Oh you are right, because there is still a record, fixed. @philtune